# Graphics Won't Render To JFrame

Tags: java, graphics, jframe

Whenever I try to render graphics to my JFrame, it does not want to show up on the JFrame.

Here is the render method:

```
public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 600);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

}
```

Here is the whole class:

```
package FrameWork;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Battle extends Canvas implements Runnable{

boolean running = false;
Thread thread;
Window gameWindow;
Handler handler= new Handler();
    public Graphics g;
    private GameObject p, e;
    private BattleWindow BattleWindow;

    public Battle(GameObject Player, GameObject Enemy){
        p = Player;
        e = Enemy;

        BattleWindow = new BattleWindow(1000, 600, "Battle", p, e, this);

    }

public void init(){
        handler.addObject(e);
        handler.object.add(p);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyInputBattle(handler));

}

public void createLevel(){

}

public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)
            return;

        running = true;
        createLevel();
        thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}


@Override
public void run() {
        init();
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("BATTLE - FPS: " + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
                frames = 0;
                updates = 0;
            }
        }
}

public void tick(){
        handler.tick();
}

public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 600);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

}

    public void dispose(){
        running = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: the code you pasted doesn't build. please provide a complete example which builds.

Comment: Graphics should be rendered to a JPanel, not a JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains many mistakes, not surprised it is not working. What is this?

```
BattleWindow = new BattleWindow(1000, 600, "Battle", p, e, this);
```

When you are creating an instance of a class, you have to give it a name:

```
BattleWindow bw = new BattleWindow(1000, 600, "Battle", p, e, this);
```

Try to look at basic syntax and rules of java and try to restate your code.

Comment: I understand I was just using bad naming conventions. I had an object Battle Window and named my variable BattleWindow. But changing the name does not solve the problem.

Comment: No it doesn't´ but you should take another look at your code and clean it up.